# Can an integer be formatted as a telephone number using Twig?

Tags: templating

Can an integer be formatted as a telephone number using Twig filters or other methods?

I have looked at the 'number_format' filter but it seems to be limited to controlling the number of decimals and how to delimited thousands.

Example; Integer variable from cms '20304050', output to HTML in twig like this: '20 30 40 50'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that you always want to add a space after every two digits, something like this using Twig's [split](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/split.html) and [join](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/join.html) filters should work:

```
{% set splitArray = "20304050"|split('', 2) %}
{% set formattedString = splitArray|join(' ') %}
```

If you want a different format, like `203 04 050`, then you could use [slice](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/slice.html):

```
{% set firstSeg = "20404050"|slice(0, 3) %}
{% set secondSeg = "20404050"|slice(3, 2) %}
{% set thirdSeg = "20404050"|slice(5, 3) %}

{% set formattedString = firstSeg ~ ' ' ~ secondSeg ~ ' ' ~ thirdSeg %}
```

Comment: What if we need to split it like this: 203 04 050

Comment: Updated answer.